# tk_popup not behaving as documented

Tags: menu, popup, tcl

`tk_popup` takes an optional fourth argument, an entry index, to tell
the display code to draw that entry centered on the x/y coordinates
given to `tk_popup`, and also to highlight that particular entry.

What I am seeing is not this though; the top-left corner of the entry
(the rectangle holding the entry, that is) is placed at x,y, the
rectangle is not centered on it, and there is no highlighting of the
entry. I have put printfs (`puts`) in the library routine `menu.tcl`
to check that `$menu activate $entry` is actually being called, and
indeed it is but it is not working as documented. I am using 8.7a5
but when I run my script with 8.6b3 `tk_popup` works as documented.

(The output of `puts "$tk_version $tcl_patchLevel"` is actually
`8.7 8.6.7`, but the tar files I built from were labelled `8.7a5`.)

Does anyone understand why this is so?

P.S. In answer to the question about platform, Unix.

P.P.S. As to versions,

& puts "[package require Tcl] [package require Tk]"
8.6.7 8.7a5

P.P.S.

A minimal working example; the menu that pops up should have
entry 3 'delete' selected.

```
set index 2

menu .menu0 -tearoff 0
.menu0 add command -label "move" -command { puts "move" }
.menu0 add command -label "close" -command { puts "close" }
.menu0 add command -label "delete" -command { puts "delete" }
.menu0 add command -label "quit" -command { puts "quit" }
.menu0 add command -label "top" -command { puts "top" }

pack [text .t]

bind .t <3> { tk_popup .menu0 %X %Y $::index }
```

Comment: The core menu code is platform-specific. On what platform are you running this?

Comment: You get the most informative version numbers from `puts "[package require Tcl] [package require Tk]"`